# How to merge a repeating value in Bigquery using SQL Function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

Is there a function in SQL for Bigquery where I can merge a repeating value?

This is the data

| Date | Product | total_session_by_day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| July 1 | Product A | 200 |
| July 1 | Product B | 200 |
| July 2 | Product A | 500 |
| July 2 | Product B | 500 |

And this is the desired output in Bigquery.

[Excel Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeWUc.png)

The idea is when I select "July 1 and 2" and "Product A and/or B" on datastudio, the value of total_session_by_day is 700.

Hope someone could help. Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a column value in a table that spans multiple rows.  What is the structure of the table that you want?

Comment: I think you just answer my question. I needed the "200" and "500" to be a column value for multiple rows. The idea here is when I select July 1 to 2 : Products A and/or B on datastudio, the value of total_session_by_day should be 700.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `SourceTable` with your table's id:

```sql
SELECT
    total_session_by_day,
    ARRAY_AGG(
        STRUCT(
            `Date`,
            Product
        ) AS r
    )
FROM SourceTable
GROUP BY total_session_by_day
```

The output will look like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had tried this one - using array_agg. But the calculation on datastudio messes up.  I needed a return value of 700 when  July 1 and 2, and Product A and/or B are selected.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to replicate BigQuery Analytical Functions (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#syntax) within Data Studio. Unfortunately, as far as I know, this isn't currently supported. You cannot reaggregate an already aggregated value in Data Studio.

Comment: It might be possible to have a workaround using parameters if your Product list is small and predefined. Is it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... Yes, it solved my problem when I use the parameters on Datastudio.